# std::copy on pointers to volatile data

Tags: c++, stl, language-lawyer, volatile

Suppose I have a input and output pointers to volatile data.....and I try to use a `std::copy` on them:

```
uint32_t volatile* input = /*    */;
uint32_t volatile* output =  /*    */;
std::copy(input,input+512,output);
```

Should this compile?  My thought is that it should, but it fails on gcc because it is trying to use `__builtin_memmove` which requires pointers to non-volatile data......link to godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/6yDzqb

So I guess my question is this:  Is this a bug in the standard library or is this allowed to fail to compile?

Comment: Technically, `uint32_t * volatile` would be a volatile pointer.  What you have here is a regular pointer which points to volatile data.

Comment: @Eljay I apologize....that is what I meant to say.....

Comment: Did you stumble upon this just as a purely academic example or are you actually using this in real code? If the latter were to be the case, I'd be curious to know what the actual use case is as genuinely legitimate uses of `volatile` seem to be quite rare…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel I am writing a bootloader for a micro controller, and I needed to copy memory from one register group of registers to another....And as far as the compiler knows, if the volatile is not there then it will see the reads and writes as pointless and optimize them away....

Comment: @DarthRubik OK, that makes sense, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this should compile. `std::copy` is specified [[alg.copy]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/alg.copy#2) to behave [as if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/as_if) the value obtained from dereferencing the iterator to each element in the source range was simply assigned to the value obtained from dereferencing the iterator to the corresponding element in the destination range. A `volatile std::uint32_t` can be assigned to a `volatile std::uint32_t` because a `volatile std::uint32_t` is not `const` [[basic.lval]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval#7).

Also, note that this [does apparently compile](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%23include+%3Calgorithm%3E%0A%0Astd::uint32_t+volatile*+input%3B%0Astd::uint32_t+volatile*+output%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++std::copy(input,+input+%2B+512,+output)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:50,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) on the trunk version of GCC (at least the one available on godbolt). So I would say this almost certainly was a bug, and it seems to be fixed now…

Apart from all that, you may want to consider including `<cstdint>` rather than `<stdint.h>` as the C Standard Library headers are only available in C++ as a deprecated compatibility feature [[depr.c.headers]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/depr.c.headers). When you do, be aware of the fact that it is unspecified [[requirements.headers]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/requirements#headers-4) whether or not the entities declared in these standard headers, such as `std::uint32_t`, are actually available in the global namespace. Thus, you may want to consider using `std::uint32_t` rather than just `uint32_t` etc. as only the former is actually guaranteed to be there…